# read: wrong version number (SSL routines, ssl3_get_record)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

`binance-http.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>


namespace beast = boost::beast;         
namespace http  = beast::http;          
namespace net   = boost::asio;          
namespace ssl   = boost::asio::ssl;     
using tcp       = boost::asio::ip::tcp; 

using executor = net::any_io_executor; 
using namespace boost::json;



boost::url make_url(boost::url_view base_api, boost::url_view method) {
    assert(!method.is_path_absolute());
    assert(base_api.data()[base_api.size() - 1] == '/');

    boost::urls::error_code ec;
    boost::url url;
    resolve(base_api, method, url, ec);
    if (ec)
        throw boost::system::system_error(ec);

    return url;
}
void fail_http(beast::error_code ec, char const* what);


namespace binapi{


    enum operation {synchronous,asynchronous};

    namespace rest{

        class httpClient : public std::enable_shared_from_this<httpClient> 
        {

        public:    
            tcp::resolver resolver_;
            beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream_;
            beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
            http::request<http::string_body>  req_;
            http::response<http::string_body> res_;
            std::string API_KEY = "v6uhUtse5Ae1Gyz72eMSbUMGw7VUDdd5AnqobMOW1Llzi4snnfP4YCyY9V74PFJ4";
            std::string secret_key = "FW8j4YobD26PVP6QLu0sv4Dv7OzrtfgQKzn8FoIMwGzMW9Y0VmX1DatbLIfXoCHV";
            std::string BASE_URL = "https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/";
            net::io_context ioc;
            value json;
            

        public:

            httpClient(executor ex, ssl::context& ctx);

            ssl::context ctxx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

            void http_call(boost::url url, http::verb action, operation o);

            void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results);

            void on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type);

            void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec);

            void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

            void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

            void on_shutdown(beast::error_code ec);

            void server_time(operation oper);

            void avg_price(std::string symbol, operation oper);


        };
    }
}


namespace binapi
{
    
    namespace rest
    {

        // Report a failure
        void fail_http(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
        {
            std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }

        httpClient::httpClient(executor ex, ssl::context& ctx)
            : resolver_(ex)
            , stream_(ex, ctx) {}


        // Start the asynchronous operation
        void httpClient::http_call(boost::url url, http::verb action, operation o) 
        {

            std::string const host(url.host());
            std::string const service = url.has_port() //
                ? url.port()
                : (url.scheme_id() == boost::urls::scheme::https) //
                    ? "https"
                    : "http";
            url.remove_origin(); // becomes req_.target()

            // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
            if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host.c_str()))
            {
                beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
                std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
                return;
            }

            // Set up an HTTP GET/POST/DELETE/PUT request message
            // req_.version(version);
            req_.method(action);
            req_.target(url.c_str());
            req_.set(http::field::host, host);
            req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
            req_.set("X-MBX-APIKEY", API_KEY);
            //req_.body() = serialize(json::object {{"symbol", "btcusdt"}});
            req_.prepare_payload(); // make HTTP 1.1 compliant

            if(o==asynchronous){
                resolver_.async_resolve(host, service,beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_resolve,shared_from_this()));
            }
            else
            {
                auto const results = resolver_.resolve(host, service);
                beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).connect(results);

                // Perform the SSL handshake
                stream_.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
                http::write(stream_, req_);

                // Receive the HTTP response    
                this->buffer_.clear();
                this->res_.clear();
                http::read(stream_, buffer_, res_);

            }
        }

        void httpClient::on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
        {
            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "resolve");            

            // Set a timeout on the operation
            beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

            // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
            beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).async_connect(results,beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_connect,shared_from_this()));
        }

        void httpClient::on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
        {
            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "connect");

            // Perform the SSL handshake
            stream_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client,beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_handshake,shared_from_this()));
        }

        void httpClient::on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
        {
            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "handshake");

            // Set a timeout on the operation
            beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

            // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
            std::cout << "Sending " << req_ << std::endl;
            
            http::async_write(stream_, req_, beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_write, shared_from_this()));
            
        }

        void httpClient::on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "write"); 

            // Receive the HTTP response
            this->buffer_.clear();
            this->res_.clear();
            http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_, beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_read,shared_from_this()));


        }

        void httpClient::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "read"); 

            // Set a timeout on the operation
            beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

            // Gracefully close the stream
            stream_.async_shutdown(beast::bind_front_handler(&httpClient::on_shutdown,shared_from_this()));
        }

        void httpClient::on_shutdown(beast::error_code ec)
        {
            if(ec == net::error::eof)
            {
                ec = {};
            }
            if(ec)
                return fail_http(ec, "shutdown");

        }

        void httpClient::avg_price(std::string symbol,operation oper)
        {
            this->server_time(operation::synchronous);
            static boost::url_view const base_api{"https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/"};
            boost::url method{"avgPrice"};
            method.params().emplace_back("symbol",symbol);
            this->http_call(make_url(base_api,method),http::verb::get, oper);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `main.cpp` looks like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "boost/url/src.hpp" // can only be included in one source file
#include "binance-ws.hpp"
#include "binance-http.hpp" 

using namespace binapi;

int main()
{
    net::io_context ioc;
    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    auto httpclients = std::make_shared<rest::httpClient>(ioc.get_executor(),ctx);

    httpclients->avg_price("BTCUSDT",operation::asynchronous);


    ioc.run();
}
```

Error : `read: wrong version number (SSL routines, ssl3_get_record)`
I think it is coming from async_read(), so i cleared all the `buffer_` and `res_` but still no clue on why its happening again.

Also I found out that, if i remove this : `this->server_time()` from
avg_price() function then it works fine.
I dont know whats really happening here, please help and advance thanks!

Comment: yeah unfortunately its the minimal i can get! I have removed all other API's.

Comment: ur right! sorry i forgot that! i will edit it out

Comment: Oh and your secret key is in this code. Now you have to log into Binance and delete this API key, before someone uses it to send themselves all your cryptocurrency (if that hasn't already happened). Removing it from the question won't work, because people can see old versions. It says testnet, so I guess they're probably fake coins for testing, but just in case...

Comment: no worries, it is the key to an artificial exchange not real one, but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: and httpClient::avg_price for example. Does the problem not occur if you directly make a http_call? I don't see the problem with your code, but someone else is more likely to, if they don't have to look at all the parts that don't cause the problem.

Comment: yep error is still there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't really see because the code is not self-contained. I do note, though, that with the code that *is* given, I cannot reproduce the problem. In fact it runs ubsan/asan clean.

The main difference is that `this->server_time` is skipped (because you didn't provide the implementation for it). So something about running two requests in succession is the problem.

Indeed, just repeating the call:

```
this->http_call(make_url(base_api, method), http::verb::get, oper);
this->http_call(make_url(base_api, method), http::verb::get, oper);
```

Does cause problems.

Then, when you read `http_call` the problem seems pretty obvious.

You never close the stream, yet, the second time around you're using the same stream, and do SNI+Handshake on it. That's not working.

A simple hack would be to reset the stream. However, if you're planning on doing full reconnects  every call, why even (a) have asynchronous mode (b) have a `httpClient` class. You likely want to keep the connection open between calls, unless errors occur.

Comment: yeah you are right, thanks! and in http_call() i didnt closed stream for synchronous mode. So i added ```stream_.shutdown().. but its still there.

Comment: I have added async mode, because when I want to request something (and not wait for it) and do other processing stuffs. Or maybe i am wrong ?

Comment: https://github.com/Naseefabu/HFTBOT/blob/master/include/binance-http.hpp
this is the full code, and it works now. i changed ```this->``` to ```std::make_shared<httpClient>(ioc.get_executor(),ctx,ioc)->``` then it worked. I thought closing the stream in synchronous mode would work...